# Как генерировать ошибку либо перенаправить на другую страницу в сигналах Django 1.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Написал сигнал. Нужно, чтобы при определённом условии генерировалась ошибка. Вроде бы, есть метод send_robust(), но как-то не удаётся это реализовать.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def currency_account_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
    if parent_user.identification_status == 'done':
        ...
    else:
        #Генерация ошибки
```

Либо же, если нельзя сгенерировать ошибку, то просто перенаправить на определённую страницу с каким-то текстом. Пробовал через *`HttpResponse`* - тоже не работает

Comment: Обработчики сигнала не связаны с запросом, а потому нет никакой возможности из них повлиять на ответ пользователя. Разве что сохранить в базу факт возникновения ошибки и в каком-нибудь представлении потом вывести. А `send_robust` для отправки сигнала.

Comment: Жаль. Мне казалось, что с игналов можно перенаправить на другую страницу. Можете подсказать, как реализовать вывод ошибки через представление? Или хотя бы перенаправление на другую страницу сделать..

Comment: Перенаправление никак не сделать. Я же написал, что обработчик сигнала не может влиять на ответ. А вывод сообщений я в подобной ситуации делал с помощью [django-stored-messages](https://github.com/evonove/django-stored-messages).

Comment: Спасибо, но я пока не совсем понимаю, как связать сигнал и сообщения во вьюхе.

Comment: В сигналах это вряд ли получится сделать. Там нужно передавать `request`, а в сигналах такого параметра нет, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Бывает полезно читать документацию. Есть метод [add_message_for](https://django-stored-messages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?#stored_messages.api.add_message_for), в который не надо передавать `request`.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. Правда, не удаётся никак вид уведомлений сменить, но это уже такое..